# "Implicit declaration of process_vm_readv", But I am including <sys/uio.h>

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to compile some code using GCC. In my code I call process_vm_readv() and process_vm_writev() (These are non-standard Linux extensions, see man-page here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/process_vm_writev).

Adhering to the man, I include  in my .c file, but GCC spits out:

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘process_vm_writev’

I'm not sure how to fix this... Standard libc functions like printf and strlen compile fine.

Comment: It seems your `libc` doesn't have it. Which libc version do you have ? Is the prototype present in `/usr/include/bits/uio.h` ?

Comment: @downvoter This is a valid question, well formated and within the scope of the site. Any reasons for downvoting ?

Comment: I should have mentioned my glibc version is 2.17 (functions are supported from version >= 2.15.) nos' answer fixed it though.

Comment: Yep. That's a great answer. I am surprised the man page doesn't mention it, it's typically mentioned straight before the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those functions are only available when GNU extensions are enabled. That is the #define  `_GNU_SOURCE` is in effect, (a fact that probably should have been documented in he man page)

So you'll need to do

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/uio.h>
```

Comment: Yep, that did it!

I reported is as a bug at the man-pages project.